# Camera Path Constraint not working as wanted

Tags: camera, constraints, path

I'm trying to make my Camera follow a path with a constraint but every time I change the offset, nothing moves except a dashed blue line follows the path in the exact way I'd want the camera to. I'm pretty confused, any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you say there:

> nothing moves except a dashed blue line follows the path in the exact
>   way I'd want the camera to

Makes me believe that you have the Influence set to 0.

Here a visual version of what i could imagine you have.
[image]

The camera or whatever object get's the follow path constraint, follows with it's position relative to the start-point on the path. Since it's not key-framed, it's still possible to adjust the location to suit your needs.

*A suggestion i would want to give you is that it might be a better idea to parent the camera to an empty and let the empty follow the path instead.
That way you can give the camera it's own constraint, for example to target an empty for easier targeting. If you then parent the target-empty to an object, it's possible to slowly focus onto the object stay with it while in motion and eventually even wander around on the object, to then finally move away from it to close a scene. (hope that tip did not burst the topic)*

Happy Blending.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I tried to adjust my settings to be similar to yours and found out it was because forward was set to Z, not quite sure what that means but setting it to X solved the problem. Also thank you for the suggestion, that really makes targeting easier, implemented it right away :) I appreciate it a lot!